# SharedPreference rulles

Tags: java, android, settings, sharedpreferences

How can I disable SharedPreferences to remove?
I create app and it has bonuses at first arrived. If user remove his cache in settings of device, application will think that it installed just now, with 0 arrived, and give user bonus. How protect of that?

Comment: I can barely understand the question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I think the question is, "is it possible to stop the user deleting shared preferences by clearing the cache".  The answer to which is no.

Comment: How can I prevent delete data (in the device settings) from user? Can I protect SharedPreference to not remove?

Comment: Simon, and there is no chance to save it?

Comment: No.  It is not possible.

Comment: Save it where?  The point of shared preferences is that that is where you save (or database but the same problem is there). The answer is to design your app so that this is not a problem.

Comment: And what about installation? Can I write anything if user install\delete\install\delete\install the app and take , bonuses?

Comment: actually you can persist the shared preferences to a file on SD or the like. But then might as well save the data in your own file in the first place. Perhaps take a look at Parse.com, think that might be one of the better options.